# Exec can't access variables in it's parent environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, exec

My friend asked me to build a function that can execute code in a for loop so, I was doing that and I was using exec in the same file I was declaring a variable `name`, now when I access `name` from exec, it says `NameError: name 'name' is not defined`

This thing is in multiple files, one that runs everything, second that includes all functions and one that calls all functions

I have tried to define variables inside exec and sure, it works.
I have tried Accessing variables in `functions.py`(File that contains every function) file and it works too.

I have tried merging `functions.py` and `test.py`(the file that's using exec) and then running it directly through python and it worked

My `functions.py` file

```py
def forloop(current, maximum, code):
    for x in range(current, maximum):
        exec(str(code), globals())
```

My 'test.py'(It's the one where I call functions)

```
from functions import *
name = 'Ameer'
forloop(1,3,"""
echo(name)
""")
```

And, I am running it all through another exec in my 'runner.py'

```
from functions import *
file = open('test.py', "r+")
content = file.read()
exec(content)
```

Now, it's giving me an error saying `NameError: name 'name' is not defined` when it is defined. Please can you guys help me with this issue

Comment: Chances are you shouldn't use exec at all, can you explain your broader use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the variables from the place where `forloop` is called.

```py
import inspect


def forloop(current, maximum, code):
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    for x in range(current, maximum):
        exec(str(code), frame.f_globals, frame.f_locals)
```

Comment: bro, thanks, it works and I want to accept your answer but, please tell me why it works because the last thing I want to do is add code to my project that I don't understand